# Threefold Convolution of a Schwartz function produces the same gaussian

Tags: fourier-analysis, normal-distribution, convolution, central-limit-theorem, schwartz-space

I am wondering if there is a way to find a (or multiple) Schwartz function f such that its threefold convolution produces the same gaussian. Aka

$ f_3\left(x\right)  = e^{-π(x-1)^2}$ where $f_3\left(x\right) = (f*f*f)$

Is there some sort of type of schwartz function that has this property?

Comment: Take the Fourier transform of the Gaussian (which is again a Gaussian, up to some factors), take the cube root, then inverse fourier transform. So the rescult is just some rescaled Gaussian.

Comment: The convolution of gaussian functions should lead to another gaussian because of the central limit theorem: adding gaussian independent random variables is equivalent to taking convolutions of their probability densities, and since the sum of iid gaussians distribute gaussian, it means that the multiple convolutions converge also to a gaussian.